# Can a non-square matrix have a full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Can a non-square matrix have a full rank?

I always see cases with square matrix with full rank but seldom with non-square matrix. Can anyone help on this?

For example, is the following matrix full rank?

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 10 \\ 
2 & 3 & 14
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My lecture slide says this does not have a full rank because any multiple of $x'=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & -1/2 \end{bmatrix}$ will give $Ax=0$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 & 10 \\ 
2 & 3 & 14
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 
1 \\
-1/2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I don't think this is correct but may I check?

Comment: Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix. By definition, $A$ has full rank if and only if $A$ has rank equal to $\min \{ n,m \}$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: How are you defining "full rank" ?

Comment: Thanks then may I ask whether the 2x3 matrix above in my example a full rank?

Comment: This is a $2 \times 3$ matrix of rank 2: by definition it is a full-rank matrix.

Comment: I see. I got it. That's what I expected. Then my lecture note is wrong. Bad professor...

Comment: Can I double check with my updated example above please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a matrix is $m \times n$, then we say it has full row rank if the rank is at least $m$ and it has full column rank if the rank is at least $n$. Unless the matrix is square, it is impossible for both to occur.

We could say that the matrix is "full rank" if the rank is $\min \{ m,n \}$. I would understand this usage, even though I don't think I've actually seen it in practice.

Comment: Non-square matrices with full rank have an important role in differential geometry (implicit function theorem in dimension $>1$, and in looking for singularities in varieties defined by equations).

Comment: Thanks then may I ask whether the 2x3 matrix above in my example a full rank?

Comment: @Eric It has rank 2, which is $\min \{ 2,3 \}$. So yes.

Comment: I see. I got it. That's what I expected. Then my lecture note is wrong. Bad professor...

Comment: @Eric What do your lecture notes say? This is really a question about terminology, so if your notes are consistent then they are not really wrong, but perhaps merely inconvenient.

Comment: Can I double check with my updated example above please?

Comment: @Eric In this example your matrix has full row rank but not full column rank. As a consequence there will be a nonzero column vector $x$ such that $Ax=0$; your lecture notes found such a vector correctly. Whether this means $A$ has or doesn't have "full rank" is just a question of one's choice of terminology.

Comment: So is it correct to say it does not have full column rank but the overall thing does have full rank?

Comment: @Eric In the sense that I said above, yes. But if it is convenient for it to work another way (for instance, it is convenient to be able to say "if $A$ has full rank than $A$ is invertible", which is not true under the definition above), then it is perfectly OK to define it another way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then it seems to be a lack of explanation of the lecture slide.